# Перенос блоков в блоке если их больше 5-ти

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Предположим у нас есть блок который мы центруем, не задавая ему ни ширины не высоты, в нём будут находится маленькие блоки. Как сделать так что-ты они сами переносились если их в "строке" больше 5-ти? Желательно использовать flexbox а не гриды.

Comment: `flex-wrap` и `max-width: calc(100% / 5);`

Comment: Что значит "центруем, не задавая ширины"? Если Вы не ограничите ширину, то не сможете отцентровать блок - он всегда будет растягиваться на 100%